# An adjective for an object that catches air

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, adjectives

I'm after a very specific word, so for the purpose of illustrating the desired meaning, let's imagine nigh-tornado-like winds are whizzing around outside and that I have unusually wide, outstretched ears; lots of surface there. As I trudge to the store, cursing under my breath, I notice folding in my satellite dish ears slightly loosens the winds' grip on me. I start to wonder if there's a word to describe this unfortunate quality of my ears.

Armed with a thesaurus, I went on an adventure to find the right word. Sadly, the only thing it turned up was the adjective *inefficient*, which does not quite capture the "object or a part of an object which catches/blocks air when the object is in movement (thereby slowing it down)" sense or its hypothetical adjective.

So my question is: **Is there a word that would describe the quality of an object to block air, thus slowing it down, i.e. the opposite of aerodynamically efficient?** I'm not finicky about it, so both adjectives and nouns are fine.

You can (*and are encouraged*) to make up words on the spot. A fascinating example I nicked off a reddit thread is *aerostagnant*.

Since one of the tags requires an example:

> My ears are as __ as a parachute.

Comment: A parachute acts as a **brake**. Is _brake_ the kind of word you need?

Comment: That's good. I was still _kind of_ hoping to get a noun I could more easily turn into an adjective, but thanks anyway! Brake is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider the *noun* ***sail*** (the ears in question are emulating the behavior of sails by catching wind) - refer to definition (2) below from ODO. There appears to be an *adjective* form ***saily*** too.

> My ears are as ***saily*** as a parachute.

ODO:

> **[sail](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/sail)** *NOUN*
>
> **1** A piece of material extended on a mast to catch the wind and propel a boat, ship, or other vessel.
>   ‘all the sails were unfurled’
>
> **2** Something resembling a sail in shape or function, in particular.
>     ‘The need for an inexpensive way to get around the solar system is
>   driving research into "solar sails."’
>
> **2.1** A wind-catching apparatus, typically one consisting of canvas or a set of boards, attached to the arm of a windmill.

TFD:

> **[Saily](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Saily)**
>   *a.*  **1.**  Like a sail.
>
> Webster's Revised Unabridged Dictionary, published 1913 by C. & G.
>   Merriam Co.

EDIT:
Another adjective related to sail (thanks to Drew) is ***saillike***.

Wiktionary:

> *Adjective*
>   **[saillike](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/saillike)** ‎(not comparable)
>   Having the form of a sail

Comment: Wow, this is just perfect! My only worry is that _saily_ somehow sounds a bit off, but that's never stopped me from using a cool word that happens to perfectly fit my use case.

Comment: Also: *sail-like*.

Comment: Yes, sail-like! Thought about it initially but somehow it slipped out of my mind.

Comment: Sail-like sounds even better! It's a little awkward if you use an intensifier like _so_, though, in which case I feel _saily_ works better. I'll give it few hours and if nothing more fitting comes up, I'm accepting this.

Answer (score 1):

In a way, you could use ***air-resistant***, as in "my ears are as (air) resistant as a parachute".

It is not really a single word, and it doesn't sound fun either. But it is used in some technical papers. For example, "The calculated values of the relative humidity for high air-resistant material show better correspondence to the..."

Comment: That's actually just as good as saily. We're on the same page here as to the register it's acceptable in being an advantage -- it can be used in a more formal context without any fear of it being "corrected".

Answer (score 1):

Them ears have a serious drag coefficient.

Comment: Swimming is real pain in the neck!